# What's the easiest way to package files into a deb?

Tags: packaging

I have a bunch of static web files that change from time to time.  Right now I'm syncing my servers up using rsync, but I'd instead like to add scripts to my git repository so that when changes are made, devs can quickly turn the static files into a deb, upload them to our apt repo, and then push an update out to the servers.

This is new to me.  All of the tutorials that I've found focus on compiling code and dependencies, but I don't need that complexity.  What's the quickest toolset that we can use to quickly package our static content into a deb?

Comment: may be you could try `ckeckinstall`. I think you could move your base path to some place, and just let checkinstall track a simple `mv` command, just test it before doing on all files, and make a backup too as usual :)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand you correct, but have you read about puppet:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Puppet_(software)
https://puppetlabs.com/puppet/what-is-puppet/

Puppet is designed to share config-files and other configurations from a server to several clients for an automated configuration, but it can do this with every file or folder you want.

The beginning with this software is a little bit tricky, but if you worked with it for a time it is very useful.

Comment: I'm very active with puppet, but it does not handle large volumes of files well.  Right now, Puppet kicks off an Exec resource which calls rsync.  I'm trying to remove the rsync step and replace it with a Package resource so that I can keep my content decoupled from my deploy/config logic.  The idea is that a dev can package their files, and push them to a repo so that Puppet can automatically deploy them without the devs having to become Puppet experts.

Comment: @GregB Good comment. I would recommend rolling this comment into your original question as it does a good job clarifying your requirements.